# Python Multiprocessing get does not timeout

Tags: python, timeout, multiprocessing

I'm testing some code to timeout a function call using multiprocessing with `Process` and `Queue`. The `Queue.get()` method takes an optional timeout parameter. I wrote the following test to confirm it throws a timeout error when the called process takes longer than what is allotted in the call to `get` but it doesn't throw the error. Can anybody tell me how I'm failing to properly test the `get` timeout? I'm on **Windows 7 with python 2**.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def f(q, t):
    time.sleep(t)
    q.put(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q, 15, ))
    p.start()
    x = q.get(1)
    print "received ", x
```

Comment: The first argument to Queue.get is whether or not to block. The second argument is the length of time to wait (in seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get), `Queue.get` receives 2 parameters: `block` and `timeout`, in that order. You should call it like this

```
q.get(timeout=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was mistakenly looking at the doc for the get method of multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult... Thanks for the help.